# How To Open An Existing File in a New Window Tab?

Tags: c#, .net, stringbuilder

I'm currently trying to implement an icon that displays a csv file's content in a new tab. Right now, it's only redownloading the file when I click on it.

Here's the code snippet:

```
string mostRecentFileName = Path.GetFileName(mostRecentFilePath);
searchResults.Append("<a href='/Settlements/" + mostRecentFileName + "' title='View CSV File' target='_blank'><i class='fa-lg fa-fw fa fa-university'></i></a>&nbsp;"); //searchResults is a stringBuilder
```

I saw in a similar post to include the `target = '_blank'` but it isn't working for me here. Does anyone know of any alternate solutions? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!